# What is the difference between cycles and NextCycles in InstrStage in LLVM tablegen?

Tags: llvm

I'm trying to learn LLVM tablegen. Right now I'm trying to understand how to define an instruction stage. I found a following comment in [llvm/include/llvm/Target/TargetItinerary.td](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/1348f57925f17a804b46034b0471f64b615bdfab/include/llvm/Target/TargetItinerary.td#L43):

```
// Instruction stage - These values represent a non-pipelined step in
// the execution of an instruction.  Cycles represents the number of
// discrete time slots needed to complete the stage.  Units represent
// the choice of functional units that can be used to complete the
// stage.  Eg. IntUnit1, IntUnit2. NextCycles indicates how many
// cycles should elapse from the start of this stage to the start of
// the next stage in the itinerary.  For example:
//
// A stage is specified in one of two ways:
//
//   InstrStage<1, [FU_x, FU_y]>     - TimeInc defaults to Cycles
//   InstrStage<1, [FU_x, FU_y], 0>  - TimeInc explicit
//
```

What is the difference between cycle and NextCycle? It looks to me they are the same thing. What am I missing?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you're just getting started with LLVM, I wouldn't worry about itineraries yet. They're optional to implement, and a lot of extra hassle. (Plus, it's not hard to add them later once you have a basic working backend.)

Comment: @ChengSun Thanks for the advice. Unfortunately for me the backend is already implemented and I'm just starting out with LLVM. I need to modify existing backend. Any advice on how to proceed?

Comment: You may get more insightful help if you try asking around in the llvm-dev mailing lists, or on IRC: http://llvm.org/docs/#community

Comment: @ChengSun What IRC can you recommend?